# Assign multiple variables from a list of file names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of file

```py
file_names=['file1.sav', 'file2.sav']
```

and a list of variables names

```py
var_names=['var1', 'var2']
```

I want to assign every item in `var_names` a `read_spss` function.

so that ill get

```py
var1= pd.read_spss('file1.sav')
var2= pd.read_spss('file2.sav')
```

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion consider using a dictionary instead of individual variable names.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the comment above the easiest way to do this is with a dictionary.

```
#create empty dictionary
files = {}

file_names=['file1.sav', 'file2.sav']
var_names=['var1', 'var2']

#loop over both file_names and var_names and use them to build the dictionary
for var_name, file in zip(var_names, file_names):
    files[var_name] = pd.read_spss(file)
```

That way then you can just access it like this `files['var1']` to get the content of `file1.sav1`.